# SQL - Loop through rows twice and retroactively change values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a code where I want to query the database to update instances of a log to reflect the final status of the project. For example:

[image: this table]

would be translated to:

[image: this table]

My code so far is:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.date, a.eval_group,
CASE WHEN a.date > b.date 
AND eval_group = ('completed' OR 'canceled')
THEN 
b.eval_group
ELSE
a.eval group
END AS new_eval_group

FROM temp as a
JOIN temp as b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here and would appreciate any direction. I'm not used to SQL and do not know how to make this function work within the language!

Comment: You probably want `AND eval_group IN ('completed', 'canceled')` in the case expression.

Comment: Why is "123" not "in progress"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this.  You seem to want the last status, which you can get using `first_value()` and a descending sort:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(eval_group) over (partition by id order by date desc) as new_eval_group
from t;
```

If you only want "finished" and "canceled", you can use `filter`:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(eval_group) filter (where eval_group in ('finished', 'canceled') over (partition by id order by date desc) as new_eval_group
from t;
```